# Can we add @EnableEurekaServer for multiple main classes in single app?

Tags: netflix-eureka

## Configure this SMS Server

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:  # Not a client, don't register with yourself
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false

server:
  port: 1111   # HTTP (Tomcat) port

## Configure this Mail Server

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:  # Not a client, don't register with yourself
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false

server:
  port: 2222   # HTTP (Tomcat) port

Comment: It might help if you explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Mainly my aim is to build micro services using spring-boot. I will have multiple services like Mail Service, SMS Service etc.. I need to run every service in a different port using single application. Can i achieve this any other ways?